# ngx-bootstraap date range picker is not working with cordova framework generated code for android

Tags: angular, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, ngx-bootstrap

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Passenger } from '../passenger';
import { PASSENGERS } from '../mock-passengers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  bsValue = new Date();
  bsRangeValue: Date[];
  maxDate = new Date();

  startDate = '';
  finishDate = '';
  travelDate = '';
  checkstatus = '';

  doughnutChartLabels = [];
  doughnutChartData = [];

  doughnutChartType = 'doughnut';

  public passengers = PASSENGERS;

  public count = 1;
  public c = [];


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {
    this.maxDate.setDate(this.maxDate.getDate() + 7);
    this.bsValue.setDate(this.bsValue.getDate() - 70);
    this.bsRangeValue = [this.bsValue, this.maxDate];

  }

  ngOnInit() {


  }
  onClickGC() {
    this.doughnutChartLabels = [];
    this.doughnutChartData = [];


    this.startDate = this.bsRangeValue[0].toString().slice(4, 15);
    this.finishDate = this.bsRangeValue[1].toString().slice(4, 15);

    var months = [
      'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
    ];
    this.startDate = this.startDate.replace(this.startDate.slice(0, 3).toString(),
      (months.indexOf(this.startDate.slice(0, 3)) + 1).toString());
    this.finishDate = this.finishDate.replace(this.finishDate.slice(0, 3).toString(),
      (months.indexOf(this.finishDate.slice(0, 3)) + 1).toString());

    this.startDate = this.startDate.split(' ').join('/');
    this.finishDate = this.finishDate.split(' ').join('/');


    var from = new Date(this.startDate);
    var to = new Date(this.finishDate);



    for (var i = 0; i < this.passengers.length; i++) {

      this.c = this.passengers[i].travelDate.split("/");
      var check = new Date(parseInt(this.c[2]), parseInt(this.c[1]) - 1, parseInt(this.c[0]));
      //check.parseInt
      this.checkstatus = check.toString();


      if (check.valueOf() >= from.valueOf() && check.valueOf() <= to.valueOf()) {

        var checkdate = this.doughnutChartLabels.indexOf(this.passengers[i].travelDate);

        if (checkdate > -1) {
          this.doughnutChartData[checkdate] = this.doughnutChartData[checkdate] + 1;

        } else {
          this.doughnutChartLabels.push(this.passengers[i].travelDate);
          this.doughnutChartData.push(this.count);

        }
      }
    }
    this.travelDate = this.doughnutChartData.toString() + this.doughnutChartLabels.toString();
  }

}
```

```html
<h2>Passengers List</h2>
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Daterangepicker" class="form-control" bsDaterangepicker [(ngModel)]="bsRangeValue">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClickGC()">
        Display Doughnut Chart
      </button></div>

    checkingDate: {{checkstatus}}
    startDate: {{startDate}}
    finishing date: {{finishDate}}
    {{travelDate}}
  </div>


  <div>


    <div style="display: block" *ngIf="doughnutChartLabels.length > 0 && doughnutChartData.length >0">

      <canvas baseChart [data]="doughnutChartData" [labels]="doughnutChartLabels" [chartType]="doughnutChartType">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

While the angular project which has date range picker and dynamically populates a chart from the mock data is working, while i do the build of it for cordova platform, there is problem.

The date range picker is shown as text box but when i click it the date range picker is not being popped up.
I have done the npm install of the dependency so if anyone can help with the problem it will be great.

Comment: Please share with us what code you have tried so far

Comment: hello, i have added the relevant code if you can have a look and see where i am going wrong, i will be glad